# tslint: How to make sure that a variable is not undefined?

Tags: tslint

As per the following screenshot, the TsLint is claiming that a variable might be undefined which is not assignable to a function's parameter.

But I have already checked and make sure that it's not undefined above passing it as the function's parameter.

Why does TsLint is still claiming that the variable might be undefined?

I can dismiss that warning by changing the code to:

```
clearTimeout(saveDraftTimer.current as unknown as number)
```

but it looks ugly, any better suggestion?

```
const saveDraftTimer = useRef<number | undefined>(undefined);
```

[image]

Comment: What is the type of `saveDraftTimer.current`? It looks like it has type `{ current: number | undefined}` and not `number | undefined`, but I could be wrong without any sample code.

Comment: `const saveDraftTimer = useRef<number | undefined>(undefined);`